# Reading .csv with R in sql server

Tags: r, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I was trying couple of ways to read *.csv* file with R in SQL server. However, its throwing an error saying as "cannot open file". Can someone please point out or help me where I was doing wrong.
Here is the code that I was trying to execute:

```
DECLARE @filepath varchar(100) = 'C:/ALL.csv'
DECLARE @rscript NVARCHAR(MAX);
  SET @rscript = N'
library(zoo)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

options(scipen = 999)
ALL <- read.csv(filepath, sep = ",", header = T)
final_df1 <- ALL
;

DECLARE @sqlscript NVARCHAR(MAX);

  EXEC sp_execute_external_script
    @language = N'R',
    @script = @rscript,
    @params = N'@filepath varchar(100)',
    @filepath = @filepath;

  GO
```

Comment: Have you tried `'C:\ALL.csv'` (with a backslash) instead of `'C:/ALL.csv'`? Also, the file path is relative to wherever the SQL Server instance is running, so it needs to be on the server's C: drive.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check the following code but I would like to notice one think , the SQL Server should have required permision to csv file folder

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TablePath
DECLARE @Path AS VARCHAR(100) ='C:/'
CREATE  TABLE #TablePath (Nm VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO #TablePath VALUES(@Path)
EXEC sp_execute_external_script
 @language = N'R',
 @script =  N'
library(zoo)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
options(scipen = 999)
var <- MySet$Nm
setwd(paste(var,""))
ALL <- read.csv(file="ALL.csv", sep = ",", header = T)
final_df1 <- ALL'
,@input_data_1 = N'SELECT Nm FROM #TablePath'
,@input_data_1_name=N'MySet'
```